# Include "0" counts in result set, DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am running a query on DB2 as such:

```
SELECT column_1, COUNT(*) AS "my_count"
FROM "my_table"
WHERE column_1 IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
AND another_column = '20150609'
GROUP BY column_1;
```

This works fine in terms of getting row counts grouped by column_1. However, the problem is that I need the result set to contain a "0" row for anything in the "IN" clause that has a 0 count.

Currently, the results look like this if 6, 7, and 8 don't have rows that satisfy the other "WHERE" conditions:

```
column_1    my_count
    1         33
    2         20
    3         14
    4          2
    5         33
    9         27
    10        16
```

Any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using a recursive CTE that generates values from 1 to 10. Once you have that series, left-join your original query to it, and you're all set:

```
WITH v (column_1) AS (
    SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column_1 + 1 FROM v WHERE column_1 <= 10
)
SELECT v.column_1, COUNT("my_table".column_1) AS "my_count"
FROM v
LEFT JOIN "my_table" ON v.column_1 = "my_table".column_1
-- Note that this predicate must be part of the LEFT JOIN condition
AND another_column = '20150609'
-- Note that this predicate might no longer be needed
WHERE "my_table".column_1 IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
GROUP BY v.column_1;
```

From your comments, I take that the `column_1` values aren't necessarily sequential. No problem, just write the equivalent query without recursive CTE:

```
WITH v (column_1) AS (
    SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 42 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1337 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
SELECT v.column_1, COUNT("my_table".column_1) AS "my_count"
FROM v
LEFT JOIN "my_table" ON v.column_1 = "my_table".column_1
AND another_column = '20150609'
GROUP BY v.column_1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The values in my "IN" clause were contrived for the example in my post; however, in my actual problem those values won't be sequential or have any particular pattern. But I think the concept of LEFT JOIN to same table should still apply? Messing with that now.

Comment: Interesting, actually gives me a "1" on the rows that would be "0" rows.

Comment: Also, do you know if there's a way to select multiple in the CTE without UNIONs? As I could have hundreds of values "IN" clause. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Ah yeah, obviously... My bad. You cannot use `COUNT(*)`. You have to use `COUNT("my_table".column_1)` instead. Fixed the answer. If you want to avoid the heavy CTE, the only thing I can think of in DB2 is to use a temporary table, or to just join the actual data that produces those `column_1` values